# Embed Next Google Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar

I have a Google Calendar embedded in my website but I want the sidebar of my website to contain the next upcoming event. Is there some kind of Calendar API that I can use to embed only the next event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/) and they also have a command line utility called [GoogleCL](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/).